# Order users by country? Feature Request

Tags: feature-request

I have the following questions:

- Is it possible to order users ranking by country?
- Is this a good option to have in Stack Exchange?
- Am I using the right site to ask that?

Comment: I think if you're asking for the website to have a new feature, the right place would be Meta.stackexchange.com; I doubt, with the recent design changes, they'd want to reintroduce differences between the SE sites, so IMHO it would be a global design feature. Be sure to check out any previous, similar questions there.

Comment: I would be interested to know what would be the interest in that for a regular SE user.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no option currently on the site for that, but there are a bunch of [Data Explorer queries](https://data.stackexchange.com/unix/queries?order_by=popular&q=country) that might work depending on what you're trying to do. It's a little tricky because the "Location" field on a user's profile is freeform, but [this one](https://data.stackexchange.com/unix/query/53058/top-users-by-country) lets you search by country, and [this one](https://data.stackexchange.com/unix/query/42162/which-country-are-the-users-from) counts up the number of users from each country.

Comment: that is exactly what I am looking for